# Responsive sticky footer menu hover effect

Tags: css, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover

how can I create menu like on the picture? [image: Image of footer menu]

**Requirements:**

- Built using Bootstrap columns, **must be responsive**
- In **normal state**, only Option and icon (green square) can be seen
- **OnHover**: The Suboption (in blue rectangle) expands pushing Option up and also Caption in red rectangle appears, also pushing the whole Option up.
- When one Menu item is hovered, **all the others must stay down, not moving**
- Expanding with animation

**Here's my fiddle attempt:** http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7878/

HTML of one item (all are wrapped in a row):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 nopadding item">
        <div class="mask">  
            <div class="inner-wrapper">
                <p>Option A</p>
                <div class="hidding-guy">
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <a href="#">Suboption</a>
                    <a href="#">Suboption</a>
                    <a href="#">Suboption</a>
                </div>
                <i class="origami o-01"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-red ">CAPTION</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.footer-menu-wrapper {
  background: #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.footer-menu-wrapper .item {
  position: relative;
}
.footer-menu-wrapper .item:hover .hidding-guy, .footer-menu-wrapper .item:hover .hidding-guy > * {
  height: auto;
}
.footer-menu-wrapper .mask {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-menu-wrapper .mask .hidding-guy {
  height: 0px;
}
.footer-menu-wrapper .mask .hidding-guy > * {
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
}

.btn-red {
  background: #e91333;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 66px;
  border: 0px transparent;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Well, how to achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter your css to:

```
.footer-menu-wrapper .mask {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ddd;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

now it behave like a dropup menu. Keep in mind that you must reset the positioning for the responsive layout like:

```
    @media (max-width: 768px){
        .footer-menu-wrapper .mask{
            position: relative;
        }
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/52VtD/7882/)

[UPDATE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/52VtD/7883/) with media query

UPDATE:

1. Hide the CAPTION - opacity: 0 and show it on hover.
2. Second hide the options - visibilety: hidden and also show it on hover.

This ist a quick solution! The rest should be simple css styling

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/52VtD/7893/)

Comment: Steven, thanks for reply. There r still 2 more issues:
1. I can still see the content of the hidding-guy element (it should be completely hidden when mouse out of the item.
2. I need the hidding-guy element to appear smoothly with animation. I enhanced your fiddle a bit, but still can't make it work.
Here goes the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7891/

Comment: Extra super cool! I will only add the animations, thank you Steven!